# Create a spring mvc application which redirect every request back to previous URL after authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I made a simple authenticated application, which had a flaw, that whenever any person tries to visit a secured link like "https://www.example.com/orders.spr", it redirects the user to login page to authenticate, but after authentication, user would be redirected to homepage. How can I make my next application so robust, that the user would stay on the same url after authentication? Things I need to know is that how to catch anonymous users in spring security, how to redirect user to same page after authentication, and how to increase session timeout to 1 hour, so that user can access the url in the time limit. Any example, tutorial or code is appriciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security provides a component that has the direct responsibility of deciding what to do after a successful authentication- the AuthenticationSuccessHandler:

maybe below code can help you to understand task flow :

```
 public class MySimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler
  implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
  
    protected Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());
 
    private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();
 
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, 
      HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
      throws IOException {
  
        handle(request, response, authentication);
        clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
    }
 
    protected void handle(HttpServletRequest request, 
      HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
      throws IOException {
  
        String targetUrl = determineTargetUrl(authentication);
 
        if (response.isCommitted()) {
            logger.debug(
              "Response has already been committed. Unable to redirect to "
              + targetUrl);
            return;
        }
 
        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);
    }
 
    protected String determineTargetUrl(Authentication authentication) {
        boolean isUser = false;
        boolean isAdmin = false;
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities
         = authentication.getAuthorities();
        for (GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority : authorities) {
            if (grantedAuthority.getAuthority().equals("ROLE_USER")) {
                isUser = true;
                break;
            } else if (grantedAuthority.getAuthority().equals("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
                isAdmin = true;
                break;
            }
        }
 
        if (isUser) {
            return "/homepage.html";
        } else if (isAdmin) {
            return "/console.html";
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }
 
    protected void clearAuthenticationAttributes(HttpServletRequest request) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session == null) {
            return;
        }
        session.removeAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION);
    }
 
    public void setRedirectStrategy(RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy) {
        this.redirectStrategy = redirectStrategy;
    }
    protected RedirectStrategy getRedirectStrategy() {
        return redirectStrategy;
    }
}
```

The most common ways to implement redirection logic after login are:

- using HTTP Referer header
- saving the original request in the session
- appending original URL to the redirected login URL

  in [this](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-redirect-login) and [this](http://www.baeldung.com/spring_redirect_after_login) articles you can see more details about spring security :

Answer (score -1):

You probably have some kind of filter that checks if the user is authenticated and redirects to the login page. Get the request URL in that filter and add it to the login page as a parameter. When the login is successful check for that parameter and if it is present redirect there. Otherwise redirect to the home page. Voilà

Answer (score -1):

You can use cookies for this purpose. So basically from which page your authentication failed you can save them in cookie and after authentication you can redirect to that previous url.

Apart from that you can have at this as well.

http://www.baeldung.com/spring_redirect_after_login